# php function 'pcntl_exec' is undefined

Tags: php

Would anyone know why my `pcntl_exec` is undefined?  I have php 5.2.14 - the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-exec.php) says it should be defined in php5.  I need an alternative to exec as my hosting provider recently  locked-down these: exec, passthru, shell_exec, system, proc_open, popen, curl_multi_exec

I got the list from: `ini_get("disable_functions")`.  I see no reason for it to be undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read the [installation instructions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcntl.installation.php)

> Process Control support in PHP is not enabled by default. You have to compile the CGI or CLI version of PHP with --enable-pcntl configuration option when compiling PHP to enable Process Control support.

and

> **Note:**
>
> Currently, this module will not function on non-Unix platforms (Windows).

Comment: I am on a Linux box, '--enable-pcntl' is defined (I checked phpinfo), and `function_exists('pcntl_exec')` returns false.

Comment: Ah, I think I know what the issue probably is.  It is neither CGI or CLI - it is an apache module.

Comment: Might be listed in disable_functions